# Taylor polynomial and third degree remainder of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f : \mathbb R^3 → \mathbb R$ be the function defined by $f(x, y, z) := e^{x^2+y+xz}cos(x)$.

Compute
the first order Taylor polynomial about $(0, 0, 0)$, the second order Taylor
polynomial about $(0, 0, 0)$, and the remainder of order $3$ about $(0, 0, 0)$.

Deduce
from the previous results that lim$_{(x,y,z)→(0,0,0)}$
$\frac{e^{x^2+y+xz}cos(x)−(1+y+ 1/2(x^2+y^2+2xz))} {\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = 0$·
Justify your answer.

My attempts:

I found $P_1(x) = 1+y$

$P_2(x) = 1+y+1/2(x^2+y^2+2xz)$

But I don't know what is the formula for computing the remainder of order 3 about $(0,0,0)$. Can someone please write it down?

Also concerning the limit, do I say that $e^{x^2+y+xz}cos(x) = P_2(x) + R_3$ (where $R_3$ = remainder of order 3) and proceed from there? If not, what shall I do?

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem helpful? In particular, the part about generalizations to multivariables.

Comment: @zugzug I found the formula, but I don't know how to apply it here in this problem. Please could you show me how?